# What is the Y function?

Tags: r

A friend of mine asked me if I understood the `Y` function. I didn't even know what it was. `? Y` did not get me anywhere.

What is it?

Comment: You probably mean the Y combinator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most common application: it enables an anonymous function to call itself recursively.

An excellent explanation can be found on [Mike Vanier's livejournal page](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html)

Comment: Errr, the Y function? Sounds more like the Y combinator!

Comment: Combinators are just functions that don't contain any free variables.